# How to keep hive table in NiFi DistributedMapCache

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to keep my hive/MySQL table in NiFi DistributedMapCache. Can someone please help me with the example?

Or please correct me if we can not cache hive table anyhow in NiFi cache.

Thanks

Comment: The DistributedMapCache feature uses a combination of `DistributedMapCacheServer` and `DistributedMapCacheClientService` services. It provides a key-value cache. I don't think it is intended to be a database cache. You could use it to store and retrieve specific key-value pairs, but not the entire table.

Comment: Thanks @JagrutSharma !. My hive table is not going to be very huge, it will have around 1 million records. So, I was just looking something so that I can load hive table into cache for the lookups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ***SelectHiveQL*** processor to pull data from Hive table and output format as **CSV** and include Header as **false**.

***SplitText*** processor to split each line as individual flowfile.

**Note** 
if your flowfile size is big then you have to use series of split text processors in series to split the flowfile to each line individually

***ExtractText*** processor to extract the key attribute from the flowfile content.

***PutDistributedMapCache*** processor

Configure/Enable ***DistributedMapCacheClientService, DistributedMapCacheServer*** controller service.

Add the Cache Entry Identifier property as your extracted attribute from ExtractText processor.

You need to change the Max cache entry size depending on the flowfile size.

To fetch the cached data you can use **FetchDistributedMapCache** processor and we need to use same exact value for the identifier that we have cached in **PutDistributedMapCache**

[image]

In the same way if you want to load data from **external sources** as we are going to have data in Avro format use **ConvertRecord** processor to convert **Avro --> CSV** format then load the data into distributed cache.

However this not an best practice to load all the data into **distributedmapcache** for the huge datasets as you can use lookuprecord processor also.